# How to transfer large amount of data from Mac to Ubuntu computer?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, mac, transfer

I've got a mac laptop from which I want to take all data, and put it on my Ubuntu computer. Since I don't have an external drive, I want to do it directly somehow. I've got the two on the same wifi network, so I suppose I can use that to transfer the (roughly 200GB of) data. I'm not sure how to do this though.

I suppose I can use ssh or something, but that's a bit too advanced. I just want to be able to click around and drag-and-drop the files and folders that I want to transfer.

Does anybody know an easy way in which I can do this?

Comment: This is not an Ubuntu related question. See http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1549?viewlocale=en_US

Answer (score 0):

You need to buy a special cable called a USB Data Transfer Cable. People often confuse this cable with an ordinary cable that has USB connections on each end. If you use an ordinary cable to connect both computers you will almost certainly cause both computers to burn up very quickly.

Comment: Alright, and how these computers see eachother then? Do they both see eachother as a USB mass storage device? Can I drop and drag from both ends then? I never heard of such a cable..